# Does runOnUiThread cause memory leak?

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-leaks, android-runonuithread

I am not sure if this code can cause a memory leak.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mButton.setText("Hey!");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
```

In the thread I use the method from the activity runOnUiThread() and I keep a reference to the button in the Runnable object.
If the activity is destroyed before the thread finishes it will keep a reference to the activity because we will reference a method from the activity and a view in the runnable. 
Could you clarify me if I'm right about that? If so, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

yes, this will cause a memory leak and if u use Thread.sleep() it blocks the whole thread you should use coroutines instead of thread.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way of solving it using java? Coroutines are only available in kotlin.